# How to auto-click a button with Prism framework in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

As the title says....
In the constructor of my ViewModel, I subscribe to an event:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<SendControlsForAnimationEvent>().Subscribe(FadeinMainButtons);
```

and then in the subscriber method, I want to write some logic that would auto-click the button:

```
private void FadeinMainButtons(string argument)
        {

        }
```

How would I do that?

Comment: You've clearly misunderstood MVVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're really doing MVVM, in your ViewModel you should have a method or command that is connected to the Click event of your button. So just call it:

```
private void FadeinMainButtons(string argument)
{
  CallMyMethod(arguement); // if it's a method
  MyClickCommand.Execute(argument); // if it's a command
}
```

Comment: Actually I would go one further. You shouldn't be calling a command from code. You should be calling a Model method. Your tiers should reference in one direction only...